# Each match in each columns of a table to array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

This is how my table `tables` looks:

[image: tables]
<sub>(source: [laiteux.dev](https://laiteux.dev/pwq))</sub>

I basically want to make an API that will return every "table" the user (Admin, here) is in, by checking if he is either in `1_1`, `1_2`, `1_3`, `1_4` or `1_5`.

This is how I tried to do it:

```php
$positions = $database->fetchAll("SELECT * FROM tables WHERE 1_1 = :username OR 1_2 = :username OR 1_3 = :username OR 1_4 = :username OR 1_5 = :username", array(":username" => "Admin"));

print_r($positions);
```

And this is what this do return:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [code] => abc123
            [1_1] => 
            [1_2] => Admin
            [1_3] => 
            [1_4] => Admin
            [1_5] => 
        )
)
```

The problems are:

1. The SQL query looks very unclean and long.
2. If the user is in `1_2` and also in `1_4`, it won't return both results.

I'd like my API to return such an array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [code] => abc123
            [location] => 1_2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [code] => abc123
            [location] => 1_4
        )
)
```

How could I please do it, in a clean way?

Comment: Then i guess better way to use `foreach` loop and compose your array with proper values.

Comment: Don't you want the `id` value?

Comment: @SergheiLeonenco My SQL request would still be that unclean and long, knowing I have even more columns than 5 :/

Comment: @Nick I have no use for it so preferably not.

Comment: You can try use `GROUP BY` clause to group your `code` elements if they exist.

Comment: @SergheiLeonenco How would you actually do that?

Comment: @Laiteux Yeah that was not the way, the entity data located at the same row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I came up with, thanks to [Nick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9473764/nick)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57470876/11879612) :

```php
$levelsSeats = array(
     1 => 8,
     2 => 4,
     3 => 2,
     4 => 1
 );

 $query = "";
 foreach($levelsSeats as $level => $seat)
     for($position = 1; $position < $seat + 1; $position++)
         $query .= $level . "_" . $position . " = :username OR ";
 $query = "SELECT * FROM tables WHERE " . substr($query, 0, -3);

 $results = $database->fetchAll($query, array(":username" => $USER["username"]));

 $output = array();
 foreach($results as $result)
     foreach($levelsSeats as $level => $seat)
         for($position = 1; $position < $seat + 1; $position++)
             if($result[$level . "_" . $position] == $USER["username"])
                 array_push($output, array("id" => $result["code"], "position" => array("level" => $level, "seat" => $position)));

echo json_encode($output);
```

Output:

```
[
    {
        "id": "abc123",
        "position": {
            "level": 1,
            "seat": 2
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "abc123",
        "position": {
            "level": 1,
            "seat": 4
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to get the data you want directly from the SQL query is to use a `UNION`, testing each column independently:

```
SELECT code, '1_1' AS location
FROM tables WHERE `1_1` = 'Admin'
UNION
SELECT code, '1_2' AS location
FROM tables WHERE `1_2` = 'Admin'
UNION
SELECT code, '1_3' AS location
FROM tables WHERE `1_3` = 'Admin'
UNION
SELECT code, '1_4' AS location
FROM tables WHERE `1_4` = 'Admin'
UNION
SELECT code, '1_5' AS location
FROM tables WHERE `1_5` = 'Admin'
```

Output:

```
code    location
abc123  1_2
abc123  1_4
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=8acb68faaed2182f3888dc8c7e4d6976)

Alternately, you can post-process your existing result:

```
$locations = array('1_1', '1_2', '1_3', '1_4', '1_5');
$output = array();
foreach ($positions as $position) {
    foreach ($locations as $location) {
        if ($position[$location] == 'Admin') {
            $output[] = array('code' => $position['code'], 'location' => $location);
        }
    }
}
print_r($output);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [code] => abc123
            [location] => 1_2
        )    
    [1] => Array
        (
            [code] => abc123
            [location] => 1_4
        )    
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/i6cBq)

Comment: This is actually an amazing answer, thanks a lot for this.
However, wouldn't there be any way to shorten the SQL query, knowing I haven't only got ``1_1`` to ``1_5`` but 15 columns?

Comment: @Laiteux one option to shorten the query would be to use `FIND_IN_SET` on the concatenated columns. See https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=b8254d6e516b76ecae497bdfb72b7cb0 Unfortunately you do have to compare every column...

Comment: I see .. Well, I guess I'll use your original answer but simply write a function to faster write the query. Thanks a lot again!

Comment: @Nick, Hey what about to use a `CASE` in the query, does that helps or not?

Comment: @SergheiLeonenco I can't see how to write a `CASE` expression that would return two values?

Comment: @Nick anyway we have to run thru the loop, but if we get `count` all columns and run thru it with the `case` and check if the value already exist? we escape number of columns, which may be more `1_n` and get the same array with your answer, right?

Comment: @SergheiLeonenco that sounds intriguing but I'm not sure I completely understand what you're saying. Perhaps you could create a dbfiddle and/or post it as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

For the query maybe you can use `MATCH(ex1, ex2, ex3) AGAINST ('$search')`

for the output parse it using PHP for loop

Comment: Won't ``AGAINST('Admin')`` as well return a result if the username is ``Admin1``?